# доступ к публичным свойствам класса в php 7.3

Tags: php, php7

Есть конструкция вида:

```
class EmailSendPassword extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $password;
    public function __construct($user, $password)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject('Ваш пароль на сайте ' . env('APP_NAME'))
            ->markdown('emails.sendpass', compact('user', 'password'));
    }
}
```

Так вот, функция `compact` начиная с php 7.3 начинает выдавать ошибку, связанную с тем, что переменная `user` не определена.
В документации, касаемо изменений в php 7.3 связанной с функцией `compact` только это замечание:

> compact() now issues an E_NOTICE level error if a given string refers to an unset variable. Formerly, such strings have been silently skipped.

Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Разумеется, если в методе `build()` прописать `$user = $this->user` проблема решается, но как обойтись без этих костылей?

Comment: интересно как вы адекватный код костылем назвали. я бы наоборот использование `compact` назвал костылем. Как ни странно, написание имени переменной в виде строкового литерала рано или поздно приведет к опечатке и косякам в коде. Он имеет смысл иногда, но не стоит им злоупотреблять и пихать куда ни попадя. Тем более что он переменные из области dblbvjcnb берет, члены класса он вам не вернет.

Comment: Насколько я помню, compact ни в одной версии не видела публичные свойства

Comment: @Дмитрий, ты ошибаешься. Найди офф. источник, что `compact` может пихать в ассоциативный массив публичные свойства класса. Может тебе какой-то "учитель" подсказал? Посмотри скрин от @u_mulder в комменте под моим ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно, до php7.3 не выводилось ничего, если переменная не определена, поэтому было исправлено. Т.е. фактически без определенных в данной оболасти видимости переменных, вызывая `compact('definedVar','undefinedVar1','undefinedVar2')` мы получали ассоциативный массив только тех переменных, которые доступны в текущей области видимости

И мое субъективное мнение, что это несовсем правильно.

Соответсвенно ваш код при вызове `compact` не передавал переменные во вьюху. Что в принципе (мне кажется) не совсем то, что ожидается.

Поэтому в каждом случае погони за красотой кода не следует забывать о его работоспособности.
Вот так будет работать:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this
        ->subject('Ваш пароль на сайте ' . env('APP_NAME'))
        ->markdown('emails.sendpass', [
            'user' => $this->user,
            'password' => $this->password
        ]);
}
```

И это уж точно не костыль

Comment: Так проблема не в том, что возвращало null, а в том, что функция compact до версии php 7.3 видела публичное свойство класса, а теперь не видет.

Comment: Ни в одной из версий публичной переменной __не видно__ https://3v4l.org/cPkVK

Comment: @u_mulder интересно, и правда не видно, более того у меня были искаженные представления о использовании публичных свойств класса. Мистика в том, что это работало в моем проекте до обновления версии php, теперь выясняю как :)

Comment: @Денис да признайтесь, что перенесли код в другой метод, и раньше были какие-нибудь входные параметры функции.

Comment: @teran мм, нет.